# “I don’t mind getting to know you more.”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

A friend of mine told me

> I don’t mind getting to know you more.

What does it mean? Does she want to know me better or doesn’t she care?

Comment: Your friend is asking you on a date. You can reply "Yes. Let's meet for coffee."

Comment: Related: [Don't mind if I do!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119673).

Answer (score 1):

"I don't mind" == "I want to"

"Getting to know you" == usually exploratory towards romance

Cheers